# Jquery editable DataTable, cell's keyup event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, datatables

I have a html table that collects rows from the database.
I want to edit a specific cell in the table, it works fine, but I want a keyup event to that cell. The problem that it works until I finish typing like in'change' event.

HTML code :

```
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>City</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            <tr>
               <td>@item.id</td>
               <td>@item.name</td>
               <td>@item.country</td>
               <td>@item.city</td>
             </tr>
          }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery :

```
var table = $("#mainTable").DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching":false,
        "bDestroy": true
});

ct = 0;
$('#mainTable').on('keyup', 'td', function(){
    table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        alert(++ct);
    });
});
```

editable-table file :

```
$(function () {
    $('#mainTable').editableTableWidget({ 
        editor: $('<input>'),
        preventColumns: [1, 2, 4] 
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code related to the inline-editing that you have used, how do you enable the editing of the rows, add that portion of the code too

Comment: Ok, I've just edited the question

Comment: that is not it i am talking about the `click` binding that invokes the inline editor just like this `$('#mainTable').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline( this );
    } );`

Comment: are you `using inline-editor` or not if yes how are you invoking it when you click on any row of the `datatable` ?